# IIS 7 URL Rewrite - get value of querystring

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

im trying to rewitre from this URL...

```
/Search/VehicleDetails.aspx?vehicle=285584
```

to this one

```
/VehicleAdvert/tella/Friend/285584
```

so far i have been playing around with the rules and have this, which doesnt work...

```
<!-- Tell a Friend -->
<rule name="Tell a Friend" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*(?:Search/VehicleDetails.aspx).*$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="vehicle=.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/VehicleAdvert/tella/Friend" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

The URL i get back is `/VehicleAdvert/tella/Friend?vehicle=285584`

what im after is -> `/VehicleAdvert/tella/Friend/285584`

can anyone suggest where im going wrong ?

thanks in advance :)

Truegilly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this solved it

```
<!-- Tell a Friend -->
<rule name="Tell a Friend" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^.*(?:Search/VehicleDetails.aspx).*$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="vehicle=(\d+)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/VehicleAdvert/tella/Friend/{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```